# DateTime dictionary faster in DEBUG mode?

Tags: c#, optimization, profiling

I'm trying to measure some performance but I've stumbled upon some very counter-intuitive result which I resist to believe. Namely, that querying a `Dictionary<DateTime>` is *faster* in DEBUG mode than it is in RELEASE mode.

Obviously, the bug must be in my measuring routine - but where? Here it is:

```
        Dictionary<DateTime, int> d1 = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();

        // fill the dictionary
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        const int items = 100000;
        for (int i = 0; i < items; i++)
        {
            DateTime item = now.AddSeconds(-i);
            d1.Add(item, i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Items ready");

        const int calls = 100000000;
        DateTime queryDate = DateTime.Now;

        // query the dictionary
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < calls; i++)
        {
            int j;
            if (d1.TryGetValue(queryDate, out j))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

I start this console app by hitting Ctl-F5, so VS is not attached. On my laptop, I get around 1200ms for DEBUG compiled version, and around 2200ms(!) in RELEASE mode.

What I've checked/tried:

- The project settings are just the default of VS 2015: "optimize code" is checked for RELEASE but not for DEBUG. To reproduce, just create a new Console app project and copy-paste the code into `Program`.
- When I measure the same thing with `int` being the key type of the dictionary, the RELEASE mode *is* slightly faster than DEBUG as expected.

Please help to uncover my blind spot!

Comment: How many times did you measure that?

Comment: Ten, twenty times. I couldn't and can't believe it.

Comment: @HansPassant: *duh*, I used x86. I knew, it's something stupid. I didn't expect "Prefer 32-bit" to be the default for new projects. Lesson learned. Do you want to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default settings for new projects in VS2015 is "Prefer 32-bit". And for this particular code, it seems that the x86 jitter is behaving sub-optimal.

According to Hans Passant:

> There isn't much that the optimizer can do to improve this code. There are two basic ways that the stack frame for the TryGetValue() call can be setup. The code generator used one way, the "modern" way by writing the arguments directly to the stack. But the optimizer used another way, the "olden" way by using PUSH. The less efficient way. This is specific to the x86 jitter, the x64 jitter doesn't have this problem.

Indeed, switching to 64-bit, the RELEASE mode becomes slightly faster as expected.